# POST an invalid object: What HTTP STATUS Code do I have to return?

Tags: c#, wcf, http, rest

I'm developing a REST service using WCF and I don't know which type of HTTP Status Code do I have to return when I `POST` an invalid `Message`. Note: A message here is like a chat message (a text and some data).

This is how I have implemented the WCF Service:

**IServiceContract**:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
    UriTemplate = "/messages",
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
    BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
Message AddMessage(Message message);
```

**Service Implementation**:

```
public Message AddMessage(Message message)
{
    OutgoingWebResponseContext ctx =
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse;

    if (message == null)
    {
        ctx.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.RequestedRangeNotSatisfiable;
        ctx.StatusDescription = "message parameter is null";

        throw new ArgumentNullException("message", "AddMessage: message parameter is null");
    }

    using (var context = new AdnLineContext())
    {
        context.Entry(message).State = EntityState.Added;
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    return message;
}
```

Now I use `RequestedRangeNotSatisfiable` (HTTP 416). But I don't know if this is the HTTP Status code to return when I POST an invalid `Message`.

**What kind of HTTP Status code do I have to return when I POST an invalid object?**

Comment: It pretty much comes down to the interpretation of "invalid". See the [Client error 4xx](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-10.4) section of the HTTP/1.1 RFC for a few options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, you will use 4xx HTTP Status Code when you can manage an exception. Otherwise, you will generate a 5xx HTTP Status Code.

For your example, you can use the `400 Bad Request HTTP Status code`.

```
10.4.1 400 Bad Request
The request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax. The client SHOULD NOT repeat the request without modifications.
```

From [W3C](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

Answer (score 0):

From RFC7231 ( https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.1 ):

> 6.5.1.  400 Bad Request
>
> The 400 (Bad Request) status code indicates that the server cannot
> or    will not process the request due to something that is perceived
> to be    a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid
> request    message framing, or deceptive request routing).